# Fitting a normal distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution, fitdistrplus

I'm using the following code to fit the normal distribution. The link for the dataset for "b" (too large to post directly) is :

[link for b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNA8.jpg)

```
setwd("xxxxxx")
library(fitdistrplus)

require(MASS)
tazur <-read.csv("b", header= TRUE, sep=",")
claims<-tazur$b
a<-log(claims)
plot(hist(a))
```

[image]

After plotting the histogram, it seems a normal distribution should fit well.

```
f1n <- fitdistr(claims,"normal")
summary(f1n)

#Length Class  Mode   
#estimate 2      -none- numeric
#sd       2      -none- numeric
#vcov     4      -none- numeric
#n        1      -none- numeric
#loglik   1      -none- numeric

plot(f1n)
```

But when I try to plot the fitted distribution, I get

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 

  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

and even the summary statistics are off for f1n.

Any ideas?

Comment: `m <- mean(claims); s <- sd(claims)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you are making confusion between `MASS::fitdistr` and `fitdistrplus::fitdist`.

- `MASS::fitdistr` returns object of class "fitdistr", and there is no plot method for this. So you need to extract estimated parameters and plot the estimated density curve yourself.
- I don't know why you load package `fitdistrplus`, because your function call clearly shows you are using `MASS`. Anyway, `fitdistrplus` has function `fitdist` which returns object of class "fitdist". There is plot method for this class, but it won't work for "fitdistr" returned by `MASS`.

I will show you how to work with both packages.

```
## reproducible example
set.seed(0); x <- rnorm(500)
```

---

**Using `MASS::fitdistr`**

No plot method is available, so do it ourselves.

```
library(MASS)
fit <- fitdistr(x, "normal")
class(fit)
# [1] "fitdistr"

para <- fit$estimate
#         mean            sd 
#-0.0002000485  0.9886248515 

hist(x, prob = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, para[1], para[2]), col = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

**Using `fitdistrplus::fitdist`**

```
library(fitdistrplus)
FIT <- fitdist(x, "norm")    ## note: it is "norm" not "normal"
class(FIT)
# [1] "fitdist"

plot(FIT)    ## use method `plot.fitdist`
```

[image]

Comment: Is it worth saying that you can estimate the parameters of the Normal distribution, optimally, via `mean(x)`, `sd(x)` ... ???

Comment: Yes (although the uncertainty of the mean is also pretty easy in closed form - uncertainty of the SD is a bit more of a nuisance)

Comment: If it's the Wald standard error, then I think the delta method approach should work:  SE(f(x)) approx. df/dx * SE(x) ... in this case f(x) is sqrt(x), so SE(sd) = 0.5/sqrt(x)*SE(var) if I did the math right. (If you have likelihood ratio-test based intervals, then they are invariant under transformation, so just take the square root of the ends of the interval.)

Answer (score 10):

**Review of previous answer**

In the previous answer I did not mention the difference between two methods. In general, if we opt for maximum likelihood inference I would recommend using `MASS::fitdistr`, because for many basic distributions it performs exact inference instead of numerical optimization. Doc of `?fitdistr` made this rather clear:

> For the Normal, log-Normal, geometric, exponential and Poisson
> distributions the closed-form MLEs (and exact standard errors) are
> used, and ‘start’ should not be supplied.
>
> For all other distributions, direct optimization of the log-likelihood
> is performed using ‘optim’.  The estimated standard errors are taken
> from the observed information matrix, calculated by a numerical
> approximation.  For one-dimensional problems the Nelder-Mead method is
> used and for multi-dimensional problems the BFGS method, unless
> arguments named ‘lower’ or ‘upper’ are supplied (when ‘L-BFGS-B’ is
> used) or ‘method’ is supplied explicitly.

On the other hand, `fitdistrplus::fitdist` always performs inference in a numerical way, even if exact inference exists. Sure, the advantage of `fitdist` is that more inference principle is available:

> Fit of univariate distributions to non-censored data by maximum
> likelihood (mle), moment matching (mme), quantile matching (qme)
> or maximizing goodness-of-fit estimation (mge).

---

**Purpose of this answer**

This answer is going to explore exact inference for normal distribution. It will have a theoretical flavour, but there is no proof of likelihood principle; only results are given. Based on these results, we write our own R function for exact inference, which can be compared with `MASS::fitdistr`. On the other hand, to compare with `fitdistrplus::fitdist`, we use `optim` to numerically minimize negative log-likelihood function.

This is a great opportunity to learn statistics and relatively advanced use of `optim`. For convenience, I will estimate the scale parameter: variance, rather than standard error.

---

**Exact inference of normal distribution**

[image]

[image]

---

**Writing inference function ourselves**

The following code is well commented. There is a switch `exact`. If set `FALSE`, numerical solution is chosen.

```
## fitting a normal distribution
fitnormal <- function (x, exact = TRUE) {
  if (exact) {
    ################################################
    ## Exact inference based on likelihood theory ##
    ################################################
    ## minimum negative log-likelihood (maximum log-likelihood) estimator of `mu` and `phi = sigma ^ 2`
    n <- length(x)
    mu <- sum(x) / n
    phi <- crossprod(x - mu)[1L] / n  # (a bised estimator, though)
    ## inverse of Fisher information matrix evaluated at MLE
    invI <- matrix(c(phi, 0, 0, phi * phi), 2L,
                   dimnames = list(c("mu", "sigma2"), c("mu", "sigma2")))
    ## log-likelihood at MLE
    loglik <- -(n / 2) * (log(2 * pi * phi) + 1)
    ## return
    return(list(theta = c(mu = mu, sigma2 = phi), vcov = invI, loglik = loglik, n = n))
    }
  else {
    ##################################################################
    ## Numerical optimization by minimizing negative log-likelihood ##
    ##################################################################
    ## negative log-likelihood function
    ## define `theta = c(mu, phi)` in order to use `optim`
    nllik <- function (theta, x) {
      (length(x) / 2) * log(2 * pi * theta[2]) + crossprod(x - theta[1])[1] / (2 * theta[2])
      }
    ## gradient function (remember to flip the sign when using partial derivative result of log-likelihood)
    ## define `theta = c(mu, phi)` in order to use `optim`
    gradient <- function (theta, x) {
      pl2pmu <- -sum(x - theta[1]) / theta[2]
      pl2pphi <- -crossprod(x - theta[1])[1] / (2 * theta[2] ^ 2) + length(x) / (2 * theta[2])
      c(pl2pmu, pl2pphi)
      }
    ## ask `optim` to return Hessian matrix by `hessian = TRUE`
    ## use "..." part to pass `x` as additional / further argument to "fn" and "gn"
    ## note, we want `phi` as positive so box constraint is used, with "L-BFGS-B" method chosen
    init <- c(sample(x, 1), sample(abs(x) + 0.1, 1))  ## arbitrary valid starting values
    z <- optim(par = init, fn = nllik, gr = gradient, x = x, lower = c(-Inf, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B", hessian = TRUE)
    ## post processing ##
    theta <- z$par
    loglik <- -z$value  ## flip the sign to get log-likelihood
    n <- length(x)
    ## Fisher information matrix (don't flip the sign as this is the Hessian for negative log-likelihood)
    I <- z$hessian / n  ## remember to take average to get mean
    invI <- solve(I, diag(2L))  ## numerical inverse
    dimnames(invI) <- list(c("mu", "sigma2"), c("mu", "sigma2"))
    ## return
    return(list(theta = theta, vcov = invI, loglik = loglik, n = n))
    }
  }
```

We still use the previous data for testing:

```
set.seed(0); x <- rnorm(500)

## exact inference
fit <- fitnormal(x)

#$theta
#           mu        sigma2 
#-0.0002000485  0.9773790969 
#
#$vcov
#              mu    sigma2
#mu     0.9773791 0.0000000
#sigma2 0.0000000 0.9552699
#
#$loglik
#[1] -703.7491
#
#$n
#[1] 500

hist(x, prob = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, fit$theta[1], sqrt(fit$theta[2])), add = TRUE, col = 2)
```

[image]

Numerical method is also rather accurate, except that the variance covariance does not have exact 0 off the diagonal:

```
fitnormal(x, FALSE)

#$theta
#[1] -0.0002235315  0.9773732277
#
#$vcov
#                 mu       sigma2
#mu     9.773826e-01 5.359978e-06
#sigma2 5.359978e-06 1.910561e+00
#
#$loglik
#[1] -703.7491
#
#$n
#[1] 500
```

Comment: made my day, finding m estimator theory on stack overflow, kudos to you